# Is this C++ singleton pattern and method exposure a good practice?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

I would like to have a singleton class and expose some of its methods publicly, that work directly on the instance. Is the code below a good pattern?

```
class Singleton
{
public:
    static Singleton& get()
    {
        // the easiest way to implement a singleton class

        static Singleton instance;

        return instance;
    }

    static void publicMethodOne()
    {
        // "redirecting" the call to the instance itself

        get().instancePublicMethodOne();
    }

    static void publicMethodTwo()
    {
        // "redirecting" the call to the instance itself

        get().instancePublicMethodTwo();
    }

private:
    Singleton() {}
    Singleton(const Singleton& s) {}
    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton& s) {}

    void instancePublicMethodOne()
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    void instancePublicMethodTwo()
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    void privateMethodOne()
    {
        // privately do stuff
    }
};


// call from outside
Singleton::publicMethodOne();
```

This basically redirects every static and public method call to the instance, and every static and public method has a pair method inside the instance.

EDIT: I want to use singleton pattern, that is sure. My question is whether this pattern to expose instance methods globally is good or not.

Comment: Singleton a good pattern? In general: no. Singleton is pretty much an anti-pattern. In almost all cases, Singleton is misused as magically glorified global data. Note, however, that global, mutable data is always bad, whether it labeled as Singleton or not.

Comment: I want to use a singleton, that is not the question. I'm asking whether or not my pattern to exposure an instance method to be available globally is good.

Comment: This seems to violate DRY.

Comment: Indeed, that's why I'm asking. It does not feel right, but I don't know any other solution.

Comment: @Semmu I suppose making all the stuff considered "member data" `static` and just using regular methods and objects isn't an option ? (thread safety left as an exercise). It was at one time a COM+ technique to keep unique identity while sharing data. (didn't say it was a *good* idea; just that its been done that way).

Comment: you just wrote bunch of useless code to emulate functions inside a namespace.

Comment: @WhozCraig The singleton itself is pretty complicated and I would like to expose only a handful of methods publicly. I don't think your recommendation is possible in this situation.

Comment: @yngum thanks for your "help", I'm pretty much aware of namespaces, I have my reason no to use them.

Comment: @Semmu It wasn't a recommendation (had I recommended anything it would have been not to use one a singleton in the first place). It is simply one technique that some people use to skirt single-instances in favor of shared content in case you hand't considered it. No worries that it doesn't fit your model. Hope something else comes along that does. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Compare these two calls yourself:

```
Singleton::publicMethodOne();
Singleton::get().publicMethodOne();
```

You just put the call to `Singleton::get` inside this static methods. It doesn't make much sense to do so. It would only inflate code.

Comment: You are right, all I do is calling the get() inside the static methods, but since it is a singleton and I want to simplify the public API, I thought it would be nice, since the user won't have to write get() everywhere.

Comment: Well, you are right too. But that public API can be large, so the class would become bigger than it deserves.